# Add space i front in a dataframe how?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in python that looks like:
`df = pd.DataFrame({'tekstkolonne': ['sten','sten\kim\rene', 'sten\kim\camilla\jens']})`
and i am trying to find the number of "\" remove everything except the text after last "\"
so that i end up with this:

`df = pd.DataFrame({'tekstkolonne': ['sten','  rene', '   jens']})`
note that in front of sten there is 0 space, and in front of rene 2 * space and in front of jens 3 * space.

Comment: Maybe using regex and the `str` function `replace`.

Comment: Using the `str` methods `rpartition` and `replace`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to use [`count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count)/[`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) inside a *listcomp*:

```
df["tekstkolonne"] = [" "*s.count("\\")+s.split("\\")[-1] for s in df["tekstkolonne"]]
```

​
Output :

```
print(df) #with both columns to see the difference

            tekstkolonne new_tekstkolonne
0                   sten             sten
1          sten\kim\rene             rene
2  sten\kim\camilla\jens             jens

print(df.to_numpy()) #as an array to reveal the whitespaces

[['sten' 'sten']
 ['sten\\kim\\rene' '  rene']
 ['sten\\kim\\camilla\\jens' '   jens']]
```